# Does Swagger/APIGateway support Java character classes in regex patterns

Tags: java, regex, aws-api-gateway

I'm attempting to use AWS API Gateway to develop a HTTP API. My request object is supposed to look like this:

```
GetStudentDetailsApiRequest {
    studentId: String,
    studentName: String,
    .
    .
    .
    .
}
```

For the studentId part, I'm attempting to set a regex pattern, something like:

```
    studentId:
      type: string
      pattern: '\p{Print}+'
```

The `\p{Print}` is the character class from Java - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html.

Referred to the following Swagger docs for setting a pattern - https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/

Once I deploy my API and attempt to make an API request, I always get an error

```
Invalid request body: [ECMA 262 regex "\p{Print}+" does not match input string "S163FF2020"]
```

I can't figure out why the regex pattern isn't being accepted? Or is this a particular standard of ECMA-262 that it doesn't support Java character classes? I'm reading the ECMA 262 spec, but cannot pinpoint to a section which says Java character classes aren't support.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ECMAScript 262 has no Unicode property classes support, `[:print:]` can be represented as [this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/tsj3WH/1) (only BMP plane, I kept the astral points out to shorten the pattern).

Comment: Oh boy, that's one long regex pattern.

Comment: Yes, they tend to be very long.